# How does the executor work?

Tags: executor

There are `WasmExecutor` and `NativeElseWasmExecutor`.

Cumulus's parachain uses https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/24855eeaacbe813d093784230de2d33f07ec1e79/polkadot-parachain/src/service.rs#L279.

Cumulus's parachain template uses https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/24855eeaacbe813d093784230de2d33f07ec1e79/parachain-template/node/src/service.rs#L100C17-L100C34.

If I try to use `WasmExecutor`, I'll get the following error:

```
Other error happened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: ...
```

How to choice a right one to use?

Can someone eleborate more about how they work in code level?